# Problem with Laravel CRUD (Edit Function)

Tags: laravel

Good day everyone. I'm quite new to new to Laravel and was doing some basic CRUD coding, I was able to code the add and view function, but I'm having a hard time with the edit and delete function.

I have 4 files, the master blade file, the `web.php` (routing), the blade file and the Form Controller.

This is the `promo.blade.php` file:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table1" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">ACTION</th>
            <th class="text-center">Offer ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">Promo Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Promo Price</th>
            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($data as $key => $item)
            <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#show" data-myofferid="{{$item->offerId}}" data-mytitle="{{$item->promoName}}" data-myprice="{{$item->promoPrice}}">
                    <span class="badge bg-success"><i class="bi bi-eye-fill"></i></span>
                </a> 
                
                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit" data-mainid="{{$item->id}}"  data-myofferid="{{$item->offerId}}" data-mytitle="{{$item->promoName}}" data-myprice="{{$item->promoPrice}}">
                    <span class="badge bg-primary"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></span>
                </a>  

                <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#delete" data-myofferid="{{$item->offerId}}" data-mytitle="{{$item->promoName}}" data-myprice="{{$item->promoPrice}}">
                    <span class="badge bg-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></span>
                </a>  
            </td>
                <td class="date text-center">{{ $item->offerId }}</td>
                <td class="date text-center">{{ $item->promoName }}</td>
                <td class="number text-center">{{ $item->promoPrice}}</td>
                <td class="number text-center">{{ $item->isActive }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<!--Start Modal Edit -->
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel160" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title white" id="add">
                    Edit Promo
                </h5>

                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i data-feather="x"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <form action="{{ route('promo.edit') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="">
                            <span style="color:red">@error('id'){{$message}} @enderror</span>
                        </div>        
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Offer ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="offerId" id="offerId" value="">
                            <span style="color:red">@error('offerId'){{$message}} @enderror</span>
                        </div>        
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Promo Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="promoName" id="promoName" value="">
                            <span style="color:red">@error('promoName'){{$message}} @enderror</span>
                        </div>        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Promo Price</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="promoPrice" id="promoPrice" value="">
                            <span style="color:red">@error('promoPrice'){{$message}} @enderror</span>
                        </div>                                           
                </div>
                        
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block">CANCEL</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-1">
                        <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block">SAVE</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                    </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal Edit-->
```

Then this is the `web.php` file, for the routing:

```
Route::get('promo.promo', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'viewRecord'])->middleware('auth')->name('promo.promo');
Route::post('promo.add', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'addPromo'])->name('promo.add');
Route::post('promo.delete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'viewDelete'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('promo.edit', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'viewRecord'])->middleware('auth')->name('promo.edit');
Route::get('promo.edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'viewDetail'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('promo.edit', [App\Http\Controllers\FormControllerPromo::class, 'edit'])->name('promo.edit');
```

This is the `master.blade.php` file:

```
<!--Start Modal edit for Promo-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event){

            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var mainid = button.data('mainid')
            var id = button.data('myofferid')
            var title = button.data('mytitle')
            var price = button.data('myprice')

            var modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(mainid);
            modal.find('.modal-body #offerId').val(id);
            modal.find('.modal-body #promoName').val(title);
            modal.find('.modal-body #promoPrice').val(price);
        })
    </script>
<!--End Modal edit for Promo-->
```

I think this is the part where the code wont execute properly.
This is the `FormControllerPromo.php` file:

```
    // view form
    public function index()
    {
        return view('promo.promo');
    }

    // view record
    public function viewRecord()
    {
        $data = DB::table('promo')->get();
        return view('promo.promo',compact('data'));
    }

    // view detail
    public function viewDetail($id)
    {
        $data = DB::table('promo')->where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('promo.promo',compact('data')); 
    }

    // edit promo
    public function edit(Request $request){
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $offerId = $request->input('offerId');
        $promoName = $request->input('promoName');
        $promoPrice = $request->input('promoPrice');

        DB::table('promo')
        ->where('id', $id)  // find your user by their email
        ->limit(1)  // optional - to ensure only one record is updated.
        ->update(array('offerId' => $offerId, 'promoName' => $promoName, 'promoPrice' => $promoPrice));  // update the record in the DB. 

        $data = DB::table('promo');
        return view('promo.promo',compact('data'));
    }
```

I've been trying to code this for almost a week now with no success, any help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: You need to include your problem. What is not working the way you are expecting? And what error are you getting?

Comment: im sorry if i didnt include, the problem is that it wont execute the update statement and will give me an error 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$offerId

Comment: updated the FormController file to what I'm coding now.. but still gives an error :(

Comment: I guess you should remove `->limit(1)` because it will query records. If you have `where` on `id` you should always get one item, because ids should be unique.

Comment: removed it, but it still didnt work :(

Comment: it's been a while since I worked with laravel, but if I remember correctly (hence why this is a comment and not an answer), you still have to get the record you want to update either by doing `->get()` or `->first()` at the end of your query, only then can you update them ( `->first()->update()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `update` seems right, should work. but when you pass the `$data` variable to your view, you should call `->get()`, because otherwise you return a query builder instance, that later raises the `Undefined property` error when trying to access `{{$item->offerId}}`.

change second last line in your example

```
//from this:
$data = DB::table('promo');

//to this:
$data = DB::table('promo')->get();

//or to this if you want to show only one record:
$data = DB::table('promo')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, it finally worked! :)

Comment: cant believe all those weeks of struggle just for 1 line of code lmao